# How to simulate groups/named groups with the parser?

Tags: haskell

There is a library [regex-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative). I want to extract the file name from Content-Disposition HTTP header looking as:

- attachment; filename="this is file name .ext"
- attachment;filename=fname.ext
- *and similar...*

It seems that the function `getFile` matches such fragments:

```hs
import Text.Regex.Applicative
...

getFile :: String -> Maybe (String, String, String)  -- prefix, RESULT, suffix
getFile hdr =
  parse
  where
    unquotedName = many $ psym (/= ' ')
    quotedName = "\"" <> many (psym (/= '"')) <> "\""
    name = "filename" <> "=" <> (quotedName <|> unquotedName)
    parse = findFirstInfix name hdr
```

but how to extract the name of the file? In standard regexp we can use **groups/named groups** like `filename=([^ ]+)`, so the name will be in the first group. But how to do it with my code above?
I tried to add something like:

```hs
newtype FN = FN String deriving Show

...
... (FN <$> many (psym (/='"')) ...
```

but it seems I am doing it wrongly.

**EDIT:**

Not sure is it the most convenient way to do it:

```hs
data FN = FN String | N deriving Show
instance Semigroup FN where
  N <> a = a
  a <> _ = a

getFilename1 hdr =
  parse
  where
    unquotedName = FN <$> (many $ psym (/= ' '))
    quotedName = (N <$ "\"") <> (FN <$> many (psym (/= '"'))) <> (N <$ "\"")
    name = (N <$ ("filename" <> "=")) <> (quotedName <|> unquotedName)
    parse = findFirstInfix name hdr
```

**EDIT:**

PS. Instead of `FN` - `Maybe (First a)` can be used sure.

Comment: Do you need to use `regex-applicative`? This might be easier using something like `Text.Parsec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*>` and `<*` instead of `<>` to drop the results of the irrelevant parts. For multiple groups, you can also use `<$>` and `<*>`. Read about parser combinators to learn more about this.

```
getFilename1 hdr = findFirstInfix name hdr
  where
    unquotedName = many $ psym (/= ' ')
    quotedName = "\"" *> many (psym (/= '"')) <* "\""
    name = "filename" *> "=" *> (quotedName <|> unquotedName)
```